# iBeacon set region and metadata from server

Tags: json, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I created the web admin interface for Beacon management wherein user can enter their Majorid & Minorid with respective information (metadata). Please have a look at the JSON. I'm getting the JSON value from URL what i mentioned in the question. But how can i create the set of region for different beacons. Still confusing to create the region for different beacon, because beacon will add from server backend.

JSON:

```
 [{"name":"Test","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"23695","minor_id":"46901","notification":"","type":"Image","product_image":"www.justdoonce.com/beacon/staging/images/product_images/visualize2.png"},

{"name":"Test1","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"42583","minor_id":"41770","notification":"","type":"Text","text_text":"<p>test</p>"}]
```

Parsing & assigning:

```
     major_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("major_id")) ;

     minor_id= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("minor_id")) ;

region_server = new Region("region_server", uuid, major_id, minor_id);  //creating region

 public void onEnteredRegion(final Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {

     if (region.getIdentifier().equals("region_server")) { 

               notify_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   }


          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), you can simply construct regions inside your loop like this:

```
String refId = id+"_"+id_major+"_"+id_minor;
Region region = new Region(refId,Identifier.parse(id),
                       Identifier.parse(id_major), Identifier.parse(id_minor));
```

The refId is a unique string that must be different for each of your regions.